# Overlay on Div thumb

Tags: jquery, css

i am working on this responsive grid gallery. Now, i've got an overlay div in every List Item and hwne i hover the div fades away. But the problem is i an not able to set the div according to the thumb size. i mean Li size. I can make it fixed but how can i make it responsive. i have created a fiddle here, try to resize the browser and you can see that the read overlay div cannot fit according to thumb.. where am i wrong? 
please tell.
thanks.
the fiddle is here
[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/s5hpA/)

```
position:absolute
```

is not working..
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
li{
    position:relative;
}
.overlay {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #e61736;
}
```

Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/fw8Gp/)**

Comment: Thanks. It Worked. I am going to accept your answer in 10 Mins. Thanks.